# Недействительность ссылок, указателей, итераторов элементов вектора при перераспределение памяти?

Tags: vector, c++

Почему они станут недействительными понятно, а вот в какой ситуации нет. Могли бы вы пример привести?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это может произойти (а может и нет, зависит от текущего распределения сегментов "свободной" памяти) когда Вы добавляете очередной элемент, а именно в момент, когда превышается текущая capacity контейнера.

Другими словами, когда содержимое контейнера копируется в новый кусок памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Не очень понимаю вопрос. Начнём сначала: недействительными они станут, например, при вызове у вектора `insert` или `erase`. Ну а если Вы просто с помощью `for_each` "пройдётесь" по вектору и выведете данные - указатели останутся действительными, но это слишком, я думаю тривиальный пример. Вообще, смысл в том, что std::vector (я думаю Вы это знаете) в STL - это так сказать "умный" динамический массив, поэтому insert и erase, как мне кажется, и делают указатели недействительными, потому что приходится при удалении элемента как бы сдвигать правую часть массива влево, а при вставке в середину нового элемента приходится сдвигать правую часть вправо + еще память выделять.